# Possible ways of sharing data across GCP VMs, which are nodes in a docker swarm orchestration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops, docker-swarm

I have deployed my services in using docker swarm orchestration, for which I am using 3 GCP VMs 1 as manager node and 2 as worker nodes. Now there is requirement of sharing data across the nodes. On doing some research over it found that, a possible solution can be to mount a NFS drive on each VM and put the shareable data on it. 
For doing this I need a NFS share on GCP itself, so my question here is that how can I get a NFS share drive. Can I convert disk from one of the existing VMs to NFS share or I will be needing a new shareable storage and if I have to take new storage which storage should I take (Bucket or FileStore) and how will again make them as NFS shareable. 
I am just trying to explore each and every possibility, please recommend what all possible solution you have, I will try to implement them and get to the best possible solution.

## EDIT 1:

Is is possible to achieve this without adding a new nfs drive. Maybe using Kubernetes's feature of `Dynamic Volume Provisioning` or by any other means?

Comment: Since this is such a hassle, usually a better approach is to avoid sharing files at all.  If the containers are all replicas of the same process then they can share a relational database; otherwise they should use network calls (_e.g._, HTTP requests) or a message queue to communicate with each other.

Comment: @DavidMaze I also tried to do so but It has become mandatory for me share data among VMs creation of log files huge model files which I have not put inside containers. I would have been easy to implement if I was on local servers, we can easily configure NFS there, but I do not have much understanding of doing similar thing on GCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point Google Cloud Filestore seems your best bet. On [the product page](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) they have the straight forward instructions:

> Simple commands to create a Filestore instance with gcloud.
>
> ```
> gcloud filestore instances create nfs-server \
>     --project=[PROJECT_ID] \
>     --zone=us-central1-c \
>     --tier=STANDARD \
>     --file-share=name="vol1",capacity=1TB \
>     --network=name="default"
> ```
>
> Simple commands to install NFS, mount your file share, and set access
>   permissions.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -y update
> sudo apt-get -y install nfs-common
> sudo mkdir /mnt/test
> sudo mount 10.0.0.2:/vol1 /mnt/test
> sudo chmod go+rw /mnt/test
> ```

The part *"convert disk from one of the existing VMs to NFS share"* is very confusing, though. Given you're trying to have a common share between machines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also wanted to know, is it possible to do such thing with Storage Buckets or not.

Comment: There is in fact GCS Fuse, but the documentation [1] outlines many limitations which seem unsuitable for your use case. 
[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

Comment: Can ```Dynamic Volume Provisioning``` of Kubernetes help in this case? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/

Comment: If you're doing Swarm for orchestration then Kubernetes wouldn't make much sense, no. Either-or. And if you're thinking about moving to Kubernetes, then use GKE instead building your own cluster on GCE.